# Extend Cases to include an additional tab with a list (AEF)

Tags: acumatica

I have been extending Acumatica screens by adding new fields accordingly. However, for this particular scenario, I want to create a new tab in the Cases screen.

This tab would include a list of items. These list of items would be a custom table that I will be adding to Acumatica.

Is this possible?
And is this the correct list of Steps?

```
1. Create table in Acumatica for the list of items 
2. Create DAC for the new table
3. Extend the Cases Graph and add a new Data View (i.e. PXSelect)
4. Edit the Cases screen so that a table and grid are added accordingly
5. Link the grid to the Data View through the Data Member property
```

I am not sure whether  you would also need to implement some additional events, but I believe that if the DAC has the correct link to the Case and the correct attributes ... it should work.

Would be much appreciated if someone helps to confirm the above approach please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a tab page containing a grid bound to a DataView on a custom DAC in the case entry screen is a supported scenario.

There are a few ways to do it. Whether you are working on a Customization Project or an Extension Library will influence how you approach this requirement.

Your steps seems all right. Here's how I would do it in a Customization Project:

1. Create a new table in the database using a DB management utility (ex: SQL Server Management Studio). Restart WebSite instance or IIS to make sure Acumatica picks up DB schema change.
2. In DB script section of the customization project, add the new table and check import table schema from database. This will ensure publishing the customization project will create the table in the database.
3. Create a new DAC for the new table, DAC name should be the table name.
4. Extend the case entry graph (CRCaseMaint) and add a new DataView on your DAC.
5. Edit the case entry screen (CR306000), add a TabPage and a grid.
6. Bound the new grid to your DataView using the DataMember property